# Regex to find and replace a year in a string

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string in my c#:

> The.Big.Bang.Theory.(2013).S07E05.Release.mp4

I need to find an occurance of `(2013)`, and replace the whole thing, including the brackets, with *_* (Three underscores). So the output would be:

> The.Big.Bang.Theory.*_*.S07E05.Release.mp4

Is there a regex that can do this? Or is there a better method?

I then do some processing on the new string - but later, need to report that '(2013)' was removed .. so I need to store the value that is replaced.

Comment: **BAZINGA...!**

Comment: @SonerGönül I was just waiting for a reference haha

Comment: string str=Regex.replace(str,@"\\(\d{4}\\)","___");

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tried with your string. It works

```
string pattern = @"\(\d{4}\)";
string search = "The.Big.Bang.Theory.(2013).S07E05.Release.mp4";
var m = Regex.Replace(search, pattern, "___");
Console.WriteLine(m);
```

This will find any 4 digits number enclosed in open/close brakets.
If the year number can change, I think that Regex is the best approach .

Instead this code will tell you if there a match for your pattern

```
var k = Regex.Matches(search, pattern);
if(k.Count > 0)
  Console.WriteLine(k[0].Value);
```

Comment: What is the 'Regex r' used for? It's assigned, but never used.

Comment: `r.Replace(search, "___", 1); //replace only first occurrence of \(\d{4}\)`

Comment: Sorry, was a leftover of a previous test. Removed now.

Comment: Thanks Steve - this looks perfect BUT ... I just edited the question with a new 'requirement' that I need to handle... Is this easily accomplished?

Answer (score 2):

Many of these answers forgot the original question in that you wanted to know what you are replacing.

```
string pattern = @"\((19|20)\d{2}\)";
string search = "The.Big.Bang.Theory.(2013).S07E05.Release.mp4";
string replaced = Regex.Match(search, pattern).Captures[0].ToString();
string output = Regex.Replace(search, pattern, "___");
Console.WriteLine("found: {0}  output: {1}",replaced,output);
```

gives you the output

```
found: (2013)  output: The.Big.Bang.Theory.___.S07E05.Release.mp4
```

Here is an explanation of my pattern too. 
`\(` -- match the (
`(19|20)` -- match the numbers 19 or 20.  I assume this is a date for TV shows or movies from 1900 to now.
`\d{2}` -- match 2 more digits
`\)` -- match )

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working snippet from a console application, note the regex `\(\d{4}\)`:

```
var r = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"\(\d{4}\)");
var s = r.Replace("The.Big.Bang.Theory.(2013).S07E05.Release.mp4", "___");
Console.WriteLine(s);
```

and the output from the console application:

```
The.Big.Bang.Theory.___.S07E05.Release.mp4
```

and you can [reference this Rubular for proof](http://rubular.com/r/Esv1nfLLm2).

Below is a modified solution taking into consideration your additional requirement:

```
var m = r.Match("The.Big.Bang.Theory.(2013).S07E05.Release.mp4");
if (m.Success)
{
    var s = "The.Big.Bang.Theory.(2013).S07E05.Release.mp4".Replace(m.Value, "___");
    var valueReplaced = m.Value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    string s = "The.Big.Bang.Theory.(2013).S07E05.Release.mp4";
        var info = Regex.Split(
            Regex.Matches(s, @"\(.*?\)")
            .Cast<Match>().First().ToString(), @"[\s,]+");
        s = s.Replace(info[0], "___");
```

Result

```
The.Big.Bang.Theory.___.S07E05.Release.mp4
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
 string str="The.Big.Bang.Theory.(2013).S07E05.Release.mp4";
 var  matches = Regex.Matches(str, @"\([0-9]{4}\)");
 List<string> removed=new List<string>();
 if (matches.Count > 0)
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < matches.Count; i++)
    {
      List.add(matches.value);
    }
  }  

 str=Regex.replace(str,@"\([0-9]{4}\)","___");

System.out.println("Removed Strings are:")
foreach(string s in removed )
{
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

output:

```
Removed Strings are:
(2013)
```

Answer (score -1):

You don't need a regex for a simple replace (you can use one, but's it's not needed)

```
var name = "The.Big.Bang.Theory.(2013).S07E05.Release.mp4";
var replacedName = name.Replace("(2013)", "___");
```

Comment: That's not in the question. The answer is a valid solution for the asked question. You're correct that it's not a solution if the year is variable.